# Spring not finding @GetMapping and @PostMapping with url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm building a blog app and in this instance I want to create a new post. I created a controller with @GetMapping and @PostMapping with value "/posts/new". I used
`th:action = "@{'/posts/new'}"` `(LINE 14)` in thymeleaf but when I start the web app, and access the localhost:8080/posts/new it gives the 404 error that the url is not found, but it is there...I double checked spelling, code...pretty much everything but just can't seem to figure out what mistake did I make. Here is the code:

post_new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Blog :: New Post</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
    <form action="#"
          th:action="@{'/posts/new'}"
          th:object="${post}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{account}" />
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{createdAt}" />
        <h2>Write new post</h2>
        <div>
            <label for="new-post-title">Title</label>
            <input id="new-post-title" type="text" th:field="*{title}" placeholder="Title"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="new-post-body">Body</label>
            <textarea id="new-post-body" th:field="*{body}"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Publish post</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PostController.java

```
package com.hellion.writeup.controller;

import com.hellion.writeup.models.Account;
import com.hellion.writeup.models.Post;
import com.hellion.writeup.service.AccountService;
import com.hellion.writeup.service.PostService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;


    @GetMapping("/posts/{id}")
    public String getPost(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Post post = postService.getPost(id, model);

        if (post != null) {
            model.addAttribute("post", post);
            return "post";
        } else {
            return "404";
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/posts/new")
    public String createNewPost(Model model){
        return postService.createNewPost(model);
    }

    @PostMapping("/posts/new")
    public String saveNewPost(@ModelAttribute Post post){
        postService.save(post);
        return "redirect:/posts/" + post.getId();
    }
}
```

PostService.java

```
package com.hellion.writeup.service;

import com.hellion.writeup.models.Account;
import com.hellion.writeup.models.Post;
import com.hellion.writeup.repository.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;;

    public Optional<Post> getById(Long id) {
        return postRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Post> getAll() {
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Post save(Post post) {
        if (post.getId() == null) {
            post.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        }

        return postRepository.save(post);
    }

    public Post getPost(Long id, Model model) {
        Optional<Post> optionalPost = getById(id);

        if (optionalPost.isPresent()) {
            Post post = optionalPost.get();
            return post;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String createNewPost(Model model){
        Optional<Account> optionalAccount = accountService.findByEmail("user.user@domain.com");

        if(optionalAccount.isPresent()){
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setAccount(optionalAccount.get());
            model.addAttribute("post", post);
            return "post_new";
        }else{
            return "404";
        }
    }
}
```

post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  land= "en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link th:href="@{/styles/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Writeup :: Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">
  <a th:href="@{'/'}">Home</a>
  <div class="post">
    <h2 th:text="${post.title}">Title</h2>
    <h5 th:text="'Written by: ' + ${post.account.getFirstName()}">Account First Name</h5>
    <h5 th:text="'Created on: ' + ${post.createdAt}">Created At</h5>
    <p th:text="${post.body}">Body text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...So basically, I got stackoverflow error and the solution to that is, because I was using Lombok and @Data annotation in my "model" package, the @Data was causing some bugs and by changing it to @Getter and @Setter the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `GET` method for `/posts/new` invokes the method `createNewPost` in the service layer. If `optionalAccount` does not exist, the page `404` is returned. A possible issue is the `optionalAccount` is empty hence returning `404`.

```
if(optionalAccount.isPresent()) {
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setAccount(optionalAccount.get());
    model.addAttribute("post", post);
    return "post_new";
} else {
    return "404";
}
```

The `th:action` should be `th:action="@{/posts/new}"`.